# Stream filter on custom objects Multidimensional array given range

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Last couple of days I have given Java 8 and lambda expressions a go. Things are clearer, crispier and more fun to implement however I have been puzzled how I can iterate on a multidimensional array given range to find the first occurrence of non-null element. For example, this is my array :

```
MyObject[][] array = new MyObject[][]; //this array is never full objects are placed at random places
```

As the comment implies I am trying to find the first occurrence or non-null object between let's say

```
array[0-5][irrelevant] 
       or
array[irrelevent][3-9]
```

The closest I got thus far is:

```
MyObject obj = Arrays.stream(grid.grid)
                .flatMap(IntStream.range(0,2)) //here it must work for any dimension given any range
                .filter(array -> array != null)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

Obviously, this does not compile because it is not an Integer element but a custom object. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats grid.grid?

Comment: and this isn't lmbda's this are java streams.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the given range is valid? What if, given `array[irrelevent][3-9]`, the actual data is `array[0] = new array[10]` but `array[1] = null` and `array[2] = new array[4]`?

Comment: Its a rectangular array and range for either x or y is guaranteed to be within bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do so using the following syntax :

```
MyObject findFirst = Arrays.stream(array).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
                       .subList(0, 3) // observe this line
                       .stream()
                       .filter(e -> e != null).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Here we convert the 2D array to a `list` using `flatMap` and then use `subList` to specify the begin and end of the index you want to search.

To specify the range, you need to pass in the values to `subList(...)`

Comment: and how is it different than my downvoted 2 hours old answer?

Comment: How does that look within given range of indices? This loops through the entire array

Comment: Ok also how does that allow me to search both horizontally or vertically on this rectangular array? Check my examples for more details

Comment: Here, we are converting the 2D array to a 1D array.  Only a horizontal range would work. Tell me how you can specify a range for a vertical search? I doubt it is feasible.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because it pointed me to how I can do this. Yes there is a feasible way because the array is rectangular so if an element is at 3,4 on the grid then it means it is at position 34 therefore within the range of 30-40.

Comment: So isn't that *still* a horizontal range again?

Comment: A vertical range can be easily implemented by a slight modification to your code. Just replace your call `.flatMap(Arrays::stream)` to take a stream of a subrange.

Answer (score 1):

While Nicholas K's answer is good for horizontal slices, it doesn't work for vertical slices. Here's an answer that does exactly what the OP wanted. Just to be clear, I've written the traditional (using for loops) way of doing it, to confirm that's what the OP intended to be done. Then, I've done it using streams. It works for both horizontal and vertical slices.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Sample data
    Object[][] array = new Object[5][10];
    array[1][5] = "this is it";  // This is the first non-null object
    array[4][7] = "wrong one";   // This is another non-null object but not the first one

    // Define range (start=inclusive, end=exclusive)
    int iStart = 0, iEnd = array.length, jStart = 3, jEnd = 9; // array[irrelevant][3-9]
    //int iStart = 1, iEnd = 3, jStart = 0, jEnd = array[0].length; // array[1-3][irrelevant]

    // Doing it the traditional way
    Object firstNonNull = null;
    outerLoop:
    for (int i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++)
        for (int j = jStart; j < jEnd; j++)
            if (array[i][j] != null) {
                firstNonNull = array[i][j];
                break outerLoop;
            }

    assert firstNonNull != null;
    assert firstNonNull.equals("this is it");

    // Doing it with Java 8 Streams
    firstNonNull = Arrays.asList(array)
            .subList(iStart, iEnd)
            .stream()
            .flatMap(row -> Arrays.asList(row)
                    .subList(jStart, jEnd)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

    assert firstNonNull != null;
    assert firstNonNull.equals("this is it");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MyObject obj = Arrays.stream(array)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I downvoted you as well because you basically did the same thing as me. I specifically asked loop through a range of index

Comment: @Eilleen - Nicholas gave the exact same answer at first, so may be there is a problem in you being able to explain your problem. You clarified what you need in comments of his answer, you could have done the same here. Anyway, thanks for giving the reason for the downvote, much appreciated.